# Cannot use mongoDB anymore

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to access Mongodb form a node.js app. But now I'm getting this weird error after playing with it.

```
[2013-02-06 18:27:36.060] [ERROR] [default] - { [MongoError: assertion db/../bson/bsonobjiterator.h:67] name: 'MongoError' }
MongoError: assertion db/../bson/bsonobjiterator.h:67
at Object.exports.toError (/Users/Development/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:108:11)
at Cursor.toArray (/Users/Development/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:152:37)
at Cursor.nextObject.self.queryRun (/Users/javiermanzanomorilla/Development/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:594:39)
at Cursor.close (/Users/javiermanzanomorilla/Development/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:947:5)
at Cursor.nextObject.commandHandler (/Users/javiermanzanomorilla/Development/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:594:21)
at Db._executeQueryCommand (/Users/javiermanzanomorilla/Development/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1692:5)
at g (events.js:192:14)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
at Server.Base._callHandler (/Users/javiermanzanomorilla/Development/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:130:25)
at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/Users/javiermanzanomorilla/Development/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:517:20)
```

anyone? It's printing on every database request

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "playing with it"? What are the last commands that were successfully sent?

Comment: it's error in your configuration

Answer (score 0):

Solved! was a mistake with mongoose!